# How to Export the Cell in Excel with same values with same Number Format in c#?

Tags: c#

I tried to export the grid to excel with number format so i used.
range.NumberFormat = "Custom";

but the type of the cell is Int32, value is 12 in the grid. but in the exported excel file having 12.00. I need to set the generic solution for all the types like In32, Double, etc., could you please any one provide the solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
range.NumberFormat = "0"
```

Comment: It doesn't works if we have a 12.3 value in grid. its shows 12 in excel file